# Details about JPEG MCU

Tags: java, jpeg, minimum-coded-unit

I want to extract the individual MCUs of JPEG file using JAVA.I could not find the information about the MCUs in JPEG headers.Information like: whether size of MCU for JPEg is 8x8, 16x8, 8x16 or 16x16? or any other information which will be required to extract individual MCUs.

So can someone please suggest me that which headers hold the information(direct or indirect) about MCUs and how can I extract the MCUs of JPEG File.

waqas

Answer (score 1):

That's specified in the SOF header. Find the standard on the interwebz, it's an open ITU standard. Find the Start of Frame header specification and look for the horizontal and vertical sampling factor.